# put <hr> in front of outline

Tags: css, outline

I have a content div which has the following attributes:

```
   { max-width: 1200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     border: 3px solid #808080;
     outline: 10px solid #E3E3E3;
     background-color: #FFF;
  }
```

In this div I have a hr which overlays the left border:

```
<div id="headerhr" class="stretchRight"><hr color="#921E27" style="height: 1px;"></div>

#headerhr {
margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
}
```

This works, but the hr lays under the outline border. How can i put the hr in front of (over) the outline?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding it is working for me? http://jsfiddle.net/Q5MXe/

Comment: It's not clear what you are assking here, also you don't need a class if you have an id declared

Comment: Your question is not edited properly. Can your segregate your CSS and HTML? do both the CSS block apply to the same div?

Comment: Mr. Alien and MarsOne... do you guys happen to know each other?

Comment: Did you mean that as a joke?

Comment: A terrible one, yes :)

Comment: Sry didn't explain my problem very well, I mean this: the hr is under the outline http://jsfiddle.net/5vLWq/

Comment: remove the negative margin of -50px and your should be fine

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/5vLWq/2/

Comment: yes, but thats what i want, the hr should overlay the border with -50px , but my problem is, that the hr goes under the outline

Comment: See my answer, you need a `z-index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add a `z-index` to your hr so it overlay's on top, but for this to work you will need to asign a `position: relative;` for the z-index to work.

## [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/MTw3X/)

## Try this:

```
#headerhr {
    margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}
```